# Duplicate Symbol - linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

Building an iOS app off a tutorial and I get this message:

```
Ld /Users/EvanBresnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstGame-ekyyaqwhjsjimddxggwkkkgblylu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirstGame.app/FirstGame normal i386
    cd /Users/EvanBresnan/Documents/Xcode/FirstGame
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/EvanBresnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstGame-ekyyaqwhjsjimddxggwkkkgblylu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/EvanBresnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstGame-ekyyaqwhjsjimddxggwkkkgblylu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/EvanBresnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstGame-ekyyaqwhjsjimddxggwkkkgblylu/Build/Intermediates/FirstGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirstGame.build/Objects-normal/i386/FirstGame.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/EvanBresnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstGame-ekyyaqwhjsjimddxggwkkkgblylu/Build/Intermediates/FirstGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirstGame.build/Objects-normal/i386/FirstGame_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/EvanBresnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstGame-ekyyaqwhjsjimddxggwkkkgblylu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirstGame.app/FirstGame

duplicate symbol _HighScoreNumber in:
    /Users/EvanBresnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstGame-ekyyaqwhjsjimddxggwkkkgblylu/Build/Intermediates/FirstGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirstGame.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/EvanBresnan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstGame-ekyyaqwhjsjimddxggwkkkgblylu/Build/Intermediates/FirstGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirstGame.build/Objects-normal/i386/Game.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It might help posting a code snippet of what you are trying to achieve. It's not easy to help without knowing what you are building or where the code breaks.

Comment: Thank you! And its off some youtube tutorial of how to make a flappy bird like app by a Matt Heany guy. This is the first time i have ever coded anything so i barely know anything to what i am doing and cannot find where i went wrong

Comment: I ended up getting it to work actually but thank you for your help now i have other problems in the program to work on smh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From error message

```
duplicate symbol _HighScoreNumber in:...
```

I'd guess that you declared global variable _HighScoreNumber in two files (or may be in a header that's imported in two files). Check where and how _HighScoreNumber is declared and move it to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently face the same issue. I know **E. Brez** got the answer but to help someone else who may suffer from the same issue I was in.

According to my application flow I am using printer related third party class to print. To use that I have created object of that class in both of my files `ImagePrintViewController` and `PrintResultViewController` separately and passed required data to it. 

In my scenario I am getting same error with variable name like `_printerSetup` in two of my files`/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../x86_64/ImagePrintViewController.o`
and `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../x86_64/PrintResultViewController.o`.

I have search in both of my file for the above variable name. But I couldn't find that.

After searching long on this I got a idea to **delete reference** of my second file i.e. `BRPrintResultViewController.h` and `BRPrintResultViewController.m` after merging code in my first file.

With this I found my solution and my code runs fine after this.